# Using php module from termux as root?

Tags: root-access, shell, termux

I'm writing a anti-thief on a clean shell using termux. I turned on the backlight with the volume buttons and I want to send photos of "thief" to myself in correspondence in the social network VKontakte. I listen to pressing the power button when the screen is off and secretly take photo by front and back camera and screenshot. Next I want to send photos in VK using PHP. Since I need to listen to the clicks I use `getevent` command.

```
script -q -c 'getevent /dev/input/event5' /dev/null | while read code; do
while read line; do
    if [ $line -eq 0 ]; then
    carr=( $code )
    code1="${carr[0]}"
    code2="${carr[1]}"
    code3="${carr[2]}"
    if [ $code1 -eq 0001 ]; then
    if [ $code2 -eq 0074 ]; then
    if [ $code3 -eq 00000001 ]; then
    time=$(date +%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M:%S)
    /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/termux-camera-photo -c 1 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/q/$time.front.jpg
    /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/termux-camera-photo -c 0 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/q/$time.back.jpg
    screencap -p /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/q/$time.scr.jpg
    /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/tsu
    /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/php /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/vkup.php
    fi
    fi
    fi
    fi
done</sys/class/leds/lcd-backlight/brightness
done
```

vkup.php

```
<?php echo "contact!"; ?>
```

To run it first I write

```
su
```

Then its script located in /system/bin

```
protect
```

Getting an error

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: library "libandroid-glob.so" not found page record for 0xb674008c was not found (block_size=64)
```

If I write sequentially in command line

```
tsu
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/php /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/vkup.php
```

Or

```
su
tsu
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/php /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/vkup.php
```

It works. But in the script does not work. I also noticed that when the command `tsu` changes

```
$ tsu
bash-4.4#
```

Probably in a script it is necessary to consider it? Or is the problem in something else? Many thanks!!!

Comment: I kindly ask the close voters to consider that the question (IMO) falls in the domain of power users who like to do things traditionally (scripting, not with x1 app for y1, x2 app for y2, etc.) and scripting is pretty much on-topic here. Please justify if you disagree.

Comment: @Firelord, sorry I don't quite understand you

Comment: There are currently three close votes pending on your question.

Comment: @Firelord, I have to remove the question?

Comment: Nah. Even if five normal close voters agree to close, you can always raise the issue on meta. Moreover, a moderator actually answered your post  and made it clear in the bottom that such questions are on-topic, so don't worry.

Comment: @Firelord, Oh, understood :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you run the commands interactively, you're not running `tsu`, letting it complete, and then running the `php` command. You're running the `php` command **inside** `tsu`'s shell. You need to use the `-c` option to `tsu` to tell it what command to run:

```
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/tsu -c '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/php /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/vkup.php'
```

You can see a fuller explanation on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274339/how-to-use-su-command-over-adb-shell). Although end-user shell scripting questions are usually welcomed here, once you start getting to questions that programmers are better able to answer, you're more likely to find help on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tsu -e
```

The option `-e` preserves your environment, and should be enough to run your script without errors.

Also note that `tsu` is just like Linux `su`, which opens **another shell** instead of running a command.